# Merge *.csv files and add filename as a column in terminal using awk

Tags: csv, awk

Summary: I have close to 500 *.csv files that I need to merge into one csv file where during the merge process the filename for each csv needs to be added in each row in a new column.

I have read many threads here on stackoverflow and beyond. I am attempting to do this in Terminal (not a script that I run in terminal). Here is what I have so far. When I run this Terminal it returns "for quote>" and does not complete. I am hoping that someone can guide me easily.

```
for f in *.csv; do awk -f  ' { x=1 ; if ( x == NR ) { print "date,ProductNumber,Brand,Description,Size,UnitType,Pack,UPC,Available,Status,Delivery Due Date"  } else { gsub(".csv","",FILENAME); print FILENAME","$0 }  }  “$f”  >  “output$f”; done
```

Each csv file is structured the same and here is some sample data:

```
ProductNumber,Brand,Description,Size,UnitType,Pack,UPC,Available,Status,Delivery Due Date
="0100503","BARNEY BUTTER","ALMOND BTR,SMOOTH","16 OZ   ","CS","   6",="0094922553584","    99","Active","          "
="0100701","NATRALIA","BODY LOTION,DRY SKIN","8.45 FZ ","EA","   1",="0835787000765","    33","Active","          "
="0101741","SAN PELLEGRINO","SPRKLNG BEV,ARANCIATA,ROS","6/11.15F","CS","   4",="0041508300360","     0","Active","          "
```

Comment: you use `-f` when you have your awk code in a file: `awk -f script.awk file ...`

Answer (score 1):

```sh
awk -v OFS=, '
    FNR == 1 {
        print "date,ProductNumber,Brand,Description,Size,UnitType,Pack,UPC,Available,Status,Delivery Due Date"
        file = FILENAME
        sub(/.csv$/, "", file)
    }
    {print file, $0}
' *.csv > out.csv
```

If the list of file is too long, then

```sh
find . -name '*.csv' -print0 | xargs -0 awk '...' > out.csv
```

Comment: I think the OP will only want the header printed once and it's already present in the input so doesn't need to be hardcoded, just have `"file"` prepended: `if (NR==1) print "file", $0`. The `find | xargs` won't work as-is if the list of file names is too long since there won't be a way to distinguish the first file from the first file in the current xargs iteration but I don't think that'll come up for 500 files anyway.

Comment: If only 1 heaer is wanted, then take the header out of awk `{ echo "header"; find ... | xargs awk '...'; } > out.txt`

Comment: Good idea, I was thinking of decorating the output with indications of which lines were the headers in the awk called from xargs and then piping all of the output to an awk script that'd only print the first indicated header line and remove the decorations added by the previous calls but what you said is much simpler!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v OFS=, '
    NR == 1 && FNR == 1 {
        file = FILENAME
        sub(/.csv$/, "", file)
        print "filename", $0
    }
    NR > 1 && FNR > 1{
        file = FILENAME
        sub(/.csv$/, "", file)
        print file, $0
    }
' *.csv > out.csv
```

This worked for me.  Keeps the first line/header from the first file, and adds a header for the column that will hold the filename, then dumps all the files.